# Getting data of a particular row in a table view controller corresponding to the click of a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to IOS development. I am working on an app in which I have few rows and a button in front of each row. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath I have created a function called buttonPressed() and in that function I want to get the data only corresponding to the button I click. Can you help me with this?

Here's what I am doing.

```
   -(void) buttonPressed: (id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
   {
       UITouch *touch= [[event allTouched] anyObject];
       CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.tableView];
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
       trackedUser = [searchResult obectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   }
```

trackedUser is the object of a class which contains the details of a user like his name, id etc. And SearchResult is an array which displays the list of usernames (on searching in the search bar) in the table view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your **cellForRowAtIndexPath-Adding button to cell** code like below

```
UIButton *yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithtarget:..] //creating UIButton with frame and target method
yourButton.tag= indexPath.row;
[cell addSubview:yourButton];
[yourButton release];
```

Then modify your **buttonPressed** method as below

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{
       UIButton *myBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
       trackedUser = [searchResult obectAtIndex:myBtn.tag];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Instead of using Touch Handlers, you can make it more simple!!
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource add tags to `UIButton` like `yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;`

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (UIButton *) sender 
{
    NSLog(@"The row %d button was pressed",sender.tag);

    //To get data, simply pass sender.tag as index in your NSArray or WhatEver you're using for storing data.
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the statement for passing the tag. I am storing the search results in the searchResult array.

Comment: @AnkitRai, see my answer, I've already showing you how to do it! `yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;`

Comment: It is throwing an exception now.
This is what I did in cellforRowAtIndexPath. 
{
UIButton *button= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 0, 40, 40)]; 
[button addTarget:self action selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed "add"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
button.tag= indexPath.row; 
[cell addSubview:button]; 
[cell setIndentationWidth:1]; 
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];

}

Comment: @AnkitRai, you're forget `: (colon)` `[button addTarget:self action selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating button then set tag to button.

```
btn.tag= indexPath.row;
```

and when your button is press then access button with tag value

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (UIButton *) sender 
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    switch (btn.tag) {
        case 0:
            //Thing you want to perform
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```